# How do I properly label/wire a switched subwoofer outlet?

Tags: electrical, home-theater

All of my home theater components are in an under-stair closet that shares a wall with the back of my living room.

I already plan to run audio to the subwoofer in the living room, with a nice cover plate, etc., but I'd also like to power the subwoofer using the switched outlet on the back of my receiver/amplifier, so I'm not powering it 24/7.

Running an extension cord directly through a bare hole in the wall seems messy, is there a way to *properly* create a switched outlet on one side of a wall with a power cord on the other? How would I properly label it?

Comment: [This answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/a/10951/33) might help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to pick up a [PowerBridge](http://www.powerbridgesolution.com/aboutpowerbridge.html) type device, they allow you to have an inlet in one location and an outlet in another.

[image]

You'll connect the inlet to the outlet using cable rated for the appropriate load (14/2 Romex most likely), this insures everything is up to code (since it's not proper to run extension cords through walls).

To make the outlet switched, you'll simply connect a switch on the hot wire of the cable between the inlet and outlet devices.

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I hoped was available / legal. I won't need a switch, the amplifier feeding the outlet will switch power to it.